# how can i get the directory of where i run my application exe file from?

Tags: c#, winforms

For example let's say i installed my application at c:\test
Then from c:\test i run my application test.exe
So i want to get in a string in my program the directory c:\test
And if i run test.exe from d:\hello
So the directory in my program will be d:\hello

The installation is made by InnoSetup but thats just to set the directory i want to install to and to run from my application .

In my application i did :

```
testDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

And i tried before also :

```
testDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath);
```

In both cases im getting the same exception couldnt find the file...

In the place i run my application from after installation there are two exe files one is the application the second is exe file the application need to work with.

So i want to get the directory from where i run my application exe file so i can also use the other exe file.

EDIT

The code :

```
class Ffmpeg
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream p;
        String pipename = "mytestpipe";
        byte[] b;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process;
        string ffmpegFileName;
        string workingDirectory;

        public Ffmpeg()
        {
            workingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);// +@"\workingDirectory";
            ffmpegFileName = @"\ffmpeg.exe";
            if (!Directory.Exists(workingDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(workingDirectory);
            }
            ffmpegFileName = workingDirectory + ffmpegFileName;
            Logger.Write("Ffmpeg Working Directory: " + ffmpegFileName);
        }

        public void Start(string pathFileName, int BitmapRate)
        {
            try
            {
                string outPath = pathFileName;
                Logger.Write("Output Video File Directory: " + outPath);
                Logger.Write("Frame Rate: " + BitmapRate.ToString());
                p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
                b = new byte[1920 * 1080 * 3]; // some buffer for the r g and b of pixels of an image of size 720p

                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                psi.FileName = ffmpegFileName;
                psi.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
                psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
                Logger.Write("ProcessStartInfo Arguments" + @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath);
                //psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process = Process.Start(psi);
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                p.WaitForConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Exception Error: " + err.ToString());
            }
        }
```

The exception is throw up on the line :

```
process = Process.Start(psi);
```

The exception is :

```
6/9/2013--6:11 PM ==> Exception Error: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at ScreenVideoRecorder.Ffmpeg.Start(String pathFileName, Int32 BitmapRate) in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Ffmpeg.cs:line 56
```

The ffmpeg.exe file and the application exe file both are in program files....etc
I can run the application from there but the application cant find the ffmpeg.exe file in there

EDIT *

Tried this code now :

```
class Ffmpeg
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream p;
        String pipename = "mytestpipe";
        byte[] b;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process;
        string ffmpegFileName = @"\ffmpeg.exe";
        string workingDirectory;

        public Ffmpeg()
        {
            workingDirectory = Application.StartupPath; //Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);// +@"\workingDirectory";
            if (!Directory.Exists(workingDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(workingDirectory);
            }
            ffmpegFileName = Path.Combine(workingDirectory, ffmpegFileName);//@"\ffmpeg.exe";
            Logger.Write("Ffmpeg Working Directory: " + ffmpegFileName);
        }

        public void Start(string pathFileName, int BitmapRate)
        {
            try
            {
                string outPath = pathFileName;
                Logger.Write("Output Video File Directory: " + outPath);
                Logger.Write("Frame Rate: " + BitmapRate.ToString());
                p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
                b = new byte[1920 * 1080 * 3]; // some buffer for the r g and b of pixels of an image of size 720p

                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                psi.FileName = ffmpegFileName;
                psi.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
                psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
                Logger.Write("ProcessStartInfo Arguments" + @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath);
                //psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process = Process.Start(psi);
                process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
                p.WaitForConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("Exception Error: " + err.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Same exception as above .

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Can you post the code that is trying to find the file? How are you constructing its filename from `testDir`?

Comment: Note that `testDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath);` is wrong. You should just use `testDir = Application.StartupPath;` otherwise you'll be one directory level too high.

Comment: Mathew nope same exception .

Comment: Have you checked the value of `psi.FileName`? (Add breakpoints or print it out)

Comment: Have you tried just getting `Application.StarupPath` to see what the value is, and seeing if that value is correct? Also, you might want to try `Path.GetFullPath("ffmpeg.exe")` And, looking at your code, the exception may make sense if that directory doesn't actually exist

Comment: Just underneath the line that says `ffmpegFileName = workingDirectory + ffmpegFileName;` add the following line: `Trace.Assert(File.Exists(ffmpegFileName));` and try running the program.

Comment: Matthew ill try second .

Comment: Matthews tried your code with the assert and got an exceptin the assetion failed.

Comment: Ok so that means you can forget everything else. You've got the filename wrong somewhere. Have you really checked the directory in Windows Explorer to see if that file really is in it? And that the filename really is exactly the same as the one in the program? (Use the debugger and set a breakpoint to look at it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location //is what you need here
```

Comment: No, he really needs `Application.ExecutablePath` (although `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` will give the same answer)

Comment: Yes but he's using `Path.GetDirectoryName()` with it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Right. What's the difference then? Why are you saying this is wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong, it's just no different from what he already tried. `testDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);`

Comment: @MatthewWatson If he tried that and it didn't work, why couldn't this be an alternative solution?

Comment: Because `testdir = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` gives an identical result to `testDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)` which he's already tried - I'm just saying it's pointless to try it with the same source data - the error must be what he's doing with that path *after* getting it. That's why I asked him to post more code.

Answer (score 0):

The `Path.GetDirectoryName()` method returns the directory path **without trailing slash**. To build a file path using it, you have to add that yourself.

Best is to let the framework do it for you, sometimes it's not the ordinary backslash:

```
ffmpegFileName = Path.Combine(workingDirectory, ffmpegFileName);
```

Comment: Yeah you should *always* use `Path.Combine` when working with filesystem paths.

Comment: While I agree that it's best to use `Path.Combine()` I think the OP was appending `"@"\ffmpeg.exe";" so the backslash should have been added.

Comment: Shadow Wizard tried your code example look my updated question now same exception as before .

Comment: @joneK when you debug and check the value you sure the path is correct?